# Is LinkedIn OpenID Connect provider? How can it be used with AWS Cognito Federated Identity?

Tags: openid-connect, linkedin-jsapi, amazon-cognito

The AWS Cognito documentation is very sketchy when it comes to explaining OpenID Connect providers or how to implement auth using say LinkedIn.
The nearest example is of SalesForce

> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/building-an-app-using-amazon-cognito-and-an-openid-connect-identity-provider/

These steps did not work for LinkedIn using it Javascript SDK.
Not able to retrieve id_token similar to FB or Google JS SDK.
AWS needs id_token to return the AWS credentials.

Anyone has successfully implemented Linked with AWS Cognito?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. It seems Linkedin does not offer full OpenID Connect. Also see this [thread on the AWS Forum.](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=697944&tstart=0)

A possible solution would be to use Cognito with [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) (which can log you in via Linkedin).

Comment: is linkedin with cognito still not possible without using auth0?

Comment: I am under the impression that this can be achieved by developer-authenticated-identities in aws https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html